# Altering Word view from Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'd like to change the view in Word from my Excel macro (which creates the Word document).

I'd like to execute: `ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView`

In my Excel macro, I have:

```vb
Dim objWord
Dim objDoc    
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
```

Comment: You're late-binding Word here; `wdWebView` has no meaning unless you've referenced the Word type library... in which case late-binding serves little purpose other than making your life much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: `ActiveWindow` is in the scope of the current host application, i.e. `Excel.Application.ActiveWindow` - if you want the Word window, you need to work off the `objWord` object.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're mixing late-binding and early-binding, and also need to reference the Word instance.

An early-binding approach might be (add a reference to the *Microsoft Word xx.0 Object Library* under *Tools* > *References*).

```
Sub MyWord()
    Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    
    wordApp.Visible = True
    Set myDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add
    wordApp.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView
End Sub
```

If you want to late-bind, note from the [`WdViewType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdviewtype) enum docs that `wdWebView` corresponds to the value 6.

```
Sub MyWord()
    Const wdWebView As Long = 6
    Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
    objWord.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* have to use early binding to use wdWebView. Instead, you could use:

```
Dim objWord As Object, objDoc As Object
Const wdWebView As Long = 6
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add
objWord.ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdWebView
```